# Why won't this draw a straight rectangle?

Tags: java, loops, drawing

1. Design a Rectangle class with the following properties.
2. Implement your Rectangle class design.
3. Try your rectangle with both the default constructor and with a constructor that can take the x and y coordinates, the length of the rectangle, and the width

I designed the Rectangle class(shown below), and when running the runner class, I am supposed to get two straight/overlapping rectangles. Instead, one of my rectangles is fine, the other is tilted.

I tried to set "pen.direction(0);" in order to fix the problem, but it had no effect.

Original Rectangle Class:

```
import gpdraw.*;

public class Rectangle {

    private double myX;
    private double myY;
    private double myWidth;
    private double myHeight;
    private static DrawingTool pen;
    private static SketchPad paper;

    public Rectangle() {
        paper = new SketchPad(500,500);
        pen = new DrawingTool(paper);
    }

    public Rectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        myX = x;
        myY = y;
        myWidth = width;
        myHeight = height;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return (2*myWidth) + (2*myHeight);
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return myWidth * myHeight;
    }

    public void draw() {
        pen.up();
        pen.move(myX, myY);
        pen.down();
        pen.forward(myWidth);
        pen.turnRight();
        pen.forward(myHeight);
        pen.turnRight();
        pen.forward(myWidth);
        pen.turnRight();
        pen.forward(myHeight);
    }
}
```

Runner Class:

```
import gpdraw.*;

public class RectangleRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SketchPad(500,500);
        Rectangle rectA = new Rectangle();
        rectA.draw();
        Rectangle rectB = new Rectangle(0, -80, 400, 160);
        rectB.draw();
        Rectangle rectC = new Rectangle(100, -100, 20, 300);
        rectC.draw();
    }
}
```

When I run the program from the Runner Class, I get 2 rectangles, one if which is tilted. I am supposed to get two rectangles that are not tilted and are overlapping. The direction of the rectangles doesn't matter.

Comment: To the person who voted this down, please explain your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the pen.move() method results in the pen's direction being recorded. In this case, you will need to re-orient the pen's direction after pen.move() to point in the direction you expect to start drawing your rectangle.

```
pen.up();
pen.move(myX, myY);
pen.direction(0)
pen.down();
```